# Counting zeros in large numpy arrays without creating them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, counting, numpy-einsum

To illustrate the problem I am facing, here is some example code:

```
a = np.round(np.random.rand(10, 15))
counta = np.count_nonzero(a, axis=-1)
print(counta)

A = np.einsum('im,mj->ijm', a, a.T)
countA = np.count_nonzero(A, axis=-1)
print(countA)
```

It creates a 2D array and counts its nonzero elements along the last axis. Then it creates a 3D array, of which the nonzero elements are again counted along the last axis.

My problem is that my array `a` is so large, that I can perform the first step, but not the second step, since the `A` array would take up too much memory.

**Is there any way to still get `countA`? That is to count the zeros in A along a given axis without actually creating the array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply use a matrix multiply (dot product) to get your result, no need to generate that massive 3D array `A`:

```
a = np.round(np.random.rand(10, 15)).astype(int)
counta = np.count_nonzero(a, axis=-1)

A = np.einsum('im,mj->ijm', a, a.T)
countA = np.count_nonzero(A, axis=-1)

assert np.all(countA == (a @ a.T))
```

This is also much faster:

```
a = np.round(np.random.rand(1000, 1500)).astype(int)

%timeit np.count_nonzero(np.einsum('im,mj->ijm', a, a.T), axis=-1)
3.94 s ± 38.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit a @ a.T
558 ms ± 6.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Also note that your first step is redundant with the second:

```
assert np.all(counta == np.diag(countA))
```

Comment: hm, this is funny... my actual array `a` does not only have zeros and ones in it (badly chosen minimal example, I didn't think of that...), which your solution relies on. But then I can just make a version of `a` with all non-zero values set to one and use your method! Thanks a lot!